# SSAS finding data with date lower or equal to selected

Tags: pivot-table, ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have SSAS cube and Excel reports based on it. Now I need to show all data with date lower or equal date pointed in filter in Excel. I can do it in DAX but I have no idea if it is even possible in SSAS/MDX. Maybe there is some way to use filter value in MDX measure? It seems to be pretty often problem but I can't find any solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MDX order function:

```
Order
(
    {
        //your set
    },
    [Measures].[Measure],//measure to order
    DESC //Order type
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/order-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it is rather not that what I am looking for. I need to take all data from selected date in filter in pivot table. So my problem mainly is how to read filter value in MDX measure, it needs to be done dynamically.